# Sets of permutations and subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

There is a group given.
$$G=\langle(14)(356)\rangle < S_6$$
I am to check whether
$L = \langle(34)(56)(13)(54) \rangle$,
$K = \langle(35)(36) \rangle$
are subgroups of $G$. How can I do it without counting all the permutations?

Comment: Is there a reason why the cycles for $L$ and $K$ are not disjoint?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any group $S$, any subgroup $G\subseteq S$, and any subgroup $\langle a\rangle\subseteq S$, we have $\langle a\rangle \subseteq G$ iff $a\in G$.

Comment: So I should check whether $(14)(356) \in L$?

Comment: @Hendrra No, the other way around. You want to know whether $L\subseteq G$, so you need to check whether the generator of $L$ is an element of $G$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it. If the generator of $L \in G$ I'm done and $L < G$? Otherwise $L$ is not the subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @Hendrra Exactly! In general, if $L$ hadn't been cyclic, you would've had to check each of its generators.